# Using decompression to generate gibberish in the style of sample text

Tags: compression

Years ago, I wrote a C program that adds random binary data to a compressed text. When you decompressed the modified file, the original text would be reproduced, followed by gibberish in the style of the sample text. Depending on what original text you would use (language, genre), the gibberish would resemble that. Most of the generated words could be at least pronounced in the language of the original text, and the generated text had punctuation and reasonable word lengths.

Is there a way to implement this idea using the current tools?

I don't remember which compression algorithm I used back then, but it was <s>a adaptive Huffman code</s> a LZ-type algorithm (thanks to mnz for jogging my memory), I think.

I tried to recreate this program, but I stumbled over the more sophisticated file structure of compressed files. They have a checksum based on the original text (which I don't know after adding the random data to the compressed file). Also, they seem to store the length of the compressed data, as the decompressed file just reproduces the original text without any added material.

Comment: You might try the ppmd algorithm in 7zip. I'm not sure, but it may be able to decode random data. The problem with most decompression algorithms is that they'll get hung up on random input pretty quickly.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/281707

Comment: Since you are seeing words and not just random letters, I would say this is a compression from the LZ family. also since the words are new and not just repetitions it is probably LZ78. I should mention that Huffman coding is in addition to the original compression scheme, and if added random noise it produces the same probability distribution which LZ78 turns to the appropriate style.

Comment: @mnz I think you are spot on. If I repeatedly choose randomly bits of model text (mostly length 1 and 2) from a model text, I get gibberish that looks a bit like the model text. Starting with parts of Shakespeare's sonnets or with parts of King John's bible will give a different style of gibberish.